# Helm + Kubernetes, load and enable extensions or modules in PHP

Tags: php, docker, kubernetes, php-extension, kubernetes-helm

i've problem when i run a php deployment with kubernetes becouse don't load the modules or extensions libraries.

My deployment file is this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: php
  labels:
    app: php
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: php
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: php
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: php
        image: php:7-fpm
        env:
          - name: PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR
            value: :/usr/local/etc/php/conf.custom
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9000
        lifecycle:
          postStart:
            exec:
              command: ["/bin/sh","-c","docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql mysqli && docker-php-ext-enable pdo pdo_mysql mysqli"]
        volumeMounts:
          - name: php-conf
            mountPath: /usr/local/etc/php/conf.custom
      volumes:
        - name: php-conf
          configMap:
            name: php
```

And my ConfigMap is this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: php
  labels:
    app: php
data:
  wordpress-custom.ini: |-
    upload_max_filesize = 100M
    post_max_size = 100M
  default.ini: |-
    extension=pdo_mysql.so
    extension=mysqli.so
```

Later i go into the Pod with command "exec -it" and i put again "docker-php-ext-enable mysqli" to check it, but i receive the message "warning: mysqli (mysqli.so) is already loaded!", but when i run the "phpinfo()" command, i see "upload_max_filesize = 100M" and "post_max_size = 100M" updated, but i can't see modules enabled.

What i can do? very thank's

Comment: How do you check phpinfo() ? Via web ? 
The problem is that your docker CMD is to run php-fpm and after container started you cannot change loaded to memory php configuration. You need to restart php-fpm to apply changes, but restart kills container and you loose all changes. To add some libraries for php you should to create your own docker image and install all your libraries into the image instead of installing it in runtime

Comment: Yes, i do check via web. Uploading to docker hub is precisely what i wanted to avoid haha but I understand you.. thank'u @Panoptik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your docker CMD is to run php-fpm

https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/bb16de8a711d1ba1dc76adf4665b3b1c06a06922/7.3/stretch/fpm/Dockerfile#L266

and after container started you cannot change loaded to memory php configuration.

You need to restart php-fpm to apply changes, but restart kills container and you loose all changes. To add some libraries for php you should to create your own docker image and install all your libraries into the image instead of installing it in runtime.

Check also this issue on github
https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/331

So answer is to create your own image and install all required extensions with docker RUN command

```
FROM php:7-fpm

RUN apt-get install php-pdo php-mysql
```

After that you have to build this image

```
docker build -t php:7-fpm-mysql .
```

push it to some docker registry. For example hub.docker.com

```
docker push php:7-fpm-mysql
```

NOTE: php mysql extension is deprecated since PHP 5.5.*, use PDO instead

Comment: Thank'u @Panoptik, Do you know some website for host free and multiple private docker repositories?

Comment: If you make some common changes like installing lib you can store this image to public registry. As for me, I use both private dockerhub registry with payment for it and my own private registry which I am going to switch to. If you have your local network you can use docker registry provided in the docker 
    docker run -d  --restart=always   --name registry  -v ~/certs:/data/certs  -v ~/data/registry/config:/etc/docker/registry  -v /data/registry/storage:/var/lib/registry -p 5000:5000 registry:2

Comment: very interesting... i will search more information about it, very thank's!

Comment: Also remembered about gitlab registry feature. I believe that it's cloud version provide free private registry for private repo
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/container_registry.html